# bad memory allocation while doing opencv2 bruteforce matcher

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I was trying out the codes from the book openCV2 computer vision applications programming cookbook under surf chapter 8 page 226 out of 304 for the brute force matcher but while executing the code I keep getting this message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7530812f in surf matrix.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002af6b4.."

I tried Googling but could not find an answer to it and I have checked the book's example and still could not find what went wrong. The break point occurs at this statement: `matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2, matches);`

I am using opencv 2.3. I've included

- C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv
- C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv2
- C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include

under additional include directories and the libraries:

- opencv_core230.lib
- opencv_highgui230.lib
- opencv_imgproc230.lib
- opencv_features2d230.lib
- opencv_calib3d230.lib

...and added `C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\lib` to the additional library directories field

Below is my code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;

    cv::Mat image1=cv::imread("C:/Users/folder/44.jpg");
    cv::Mat image2=cv::imread("C:/Users/folder/44.jpg");
    cv::Mat featureImage=cv::imread("C:/Users/folder/44.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("MyJPG", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
    cv::imshow("MyJPG", image1);
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector surf(2500);
    surf.detect(image1, keypoints1);

    // Draw the keypoints with scale and orientation information
    cv::drawKeypoints(image1, // original image 
        keypoints1, // vector of keypoints 
        featureImage, // the resulting image
        cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), // color of the points
        cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG); //flag 
    cv::imshow("Results", featureImage);

    cv::imshow("MyJPG2", image2);
    surf.detect(image2, keypoints2);
    cv::drawKeypoints(image2, // original image keypoints2, // vector of
        keypoints image2, // the resulting image 
    cv::Scalar(255,255,255), // color of the points
    cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG); //flag


    // Construction of the SURF descriptor extractor
    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc1;
    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc2; // Extraction of the SURF descriptors 
    cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    surfDesc1.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    //printf("%s",surfDesc);
    surfDesc2.compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors2);
    cvWaitKey(0);  //  Construction of the matcher 
    cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float>> matcher; // Match the two image descriptors 
    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

    //cvReleaseImage( &image1 );  
    cvDestroyWindow("MyJPG");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did my best to format the code, but had to guess in a few places.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about that. I didnt think it would mess up after using block quotes. I just edited and checked again :)